# Android Registration don't work

Tags: php, android, retrofit

i am trying to code a registration system for my app, but it don't work and I don't know why.

I have written a api in php, it contains 3 files:

Here the index.php

```
<?php
require_once 'Functions.php';

$func = new Functions();

if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == 'POST'){
     $data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));

     if(isset($data -> operation)){
         $operation = $data -> operation;

         if(!empty($operation)){
              if($operation == 'register'){
                  if(isset($data -> user) && !empty($data -> user) && isset($data -> user -> firstname) && isset($data -> user ->lastname) && isset($data -> user -> birthday) && isset($data -> user -> gender) && isset($data -> user -> email) && isset($data -> user -> username) && isset($data -> user -> password)){

                    $user = $data -> user;
                    $firstname = $user -> firstname;
                    $lastname = $user -> lastname;
                    $birthday = $user -> birthday;
                    $gender = $user -> gender;
                    $email = $user -> email;
                    $username = $user -> username;
                    $password = $user -> password;

                    if($func -> isEmailValid($email)){
                        echo $func -> registerUser($firstname, $lastname, $gender, $birthday, $email, $username, $password);
                    }else{
                        echo $func -> getMsgInvalidEmail();
                    }

                }else{
                     echo $func -> getMsgInvalidParam();
                }
             }else if($operation == 'login'){
                 if(isset($data -> user) && !empty($data -> user) && isset($data -> user -> email) && isset($data -> user -> password)){

                     $user = $data -> user;
                     $email = $user -> email;
                     $password = $user -> password;

                     echo $func -> loginUser($email, $password);

                 }else{
                     echo $func -> getMsgInvalidParam();
                 }
             }else if($operation == 'chgPass'){
                  if(isset($data -> user) && !empty($data -> user) && isset($data -> user -> email) && isset($data -> user -> old_password) && isset($data -> user -> new_password)){

                     $user = $data -> user;
                     $email = $user -> email;
                     $old_password = $user -> old_password;
                     $new_password = $user -> new_password;

                     echo $func -> changePassword($email, $old_password, $new_password);

                    }else{
                        echo $func -> getMsgInvalidParam();
                    }
                 }
            }else{
                 echo $func -> getMsgParamNotEmpty();
            }
        }else{
            echo $func -> getMsgInvalidParam();
        }

}else if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "GET"){
     echo "Raivel Login API";
}
```

Functions.php:

```
<?php

require_once 'DBOperations.php';

class Functions{

private $db;

public function _construct(){
    $this -> db = new DBOperations();
}

public function registerUser($firstname, $lastname, $gender, $birthday, $email, $username, $password){
    $db = $this -> db;

    if(!empty($firstname) && !empty($lastname) && !empty($gender) && !empty($birthday) && !empty($email) && !empty($username) && !empty($password)){

        if($db -> checkUserExist($email)){
            $response["result"] = "failure";
            $response["message"] = "User already registered!";
            return json_encode($response);
        }else{
            $result = $db -> insertData($firstname, $lastname, $gender, $birthday, $email, $username, $password);

            if($result){
                $response["result"] = "success";
                $response["message"] = "User registered successfully!";
                return json_decode($response);
            }else{
                $response["result"] = "failure";
                $response["message"] = "Registration failure!";
                return json_decode($response);
            }
        }
    }else{
        return $this -> getMsgParamNotEmpty();
    }

}

public function loginUser($email, $password){
    $db = $this -> db;

    if(!empty($email) && !empty($password)){

        if($db -> checkUserExist($email)){
            $result = $db -> checkLogin($email, $password);
            if(!$result){
                $response["result"] = "failure";
                $response["message"] = "Invaild login credentials";
                return json_encode($response);
            }else{
                $response["result"] = "success";
                $response["message"] = "Login successful";
                $response["user"] = $result;
                return json_encode($response);
            }
        }else{
            $response["result"] = "failure";
            $response["message"] = "Invaild Login Credentials!";
            return json_encode($response);
        }
    }else{
        return $this -> getMsgParamNotEmpty();
    }

}

public function changePassword($email, $old_password, $new_password){
    $db = $this -> db;

    if(!empty($email) && !empty($old_password) && !empty($new_password)){
        if(!$db -> checkLogin($email, $old_password)){
            $response["result"] = "failure";
            $response["message"] = 'Invalid old password!';
            return json_encode($response);
        }else{
            $result = $db -> changePassword($email, $new_password);

            if($result) {

                $response["result"] = "success";
                $response["message"] = "Password changed successfully!";
                return json_encode($response);

            } else {

                $response["result"] = "failure";
                $response["message"] = 'Error updating password!';
                return json_encode($response);

            }
        }
    }else{
        return $this -> getMsgParamNotEmpty();
    }
}

public function isEmailValid($email){
    return filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);
}

public function getMsgParamNotEmpty(){
    $response["result"] = "failure";
    $response["message"] = "Parameters should not be empty!";
    return  json_encode($response);
}

public function getMsgInvalidEmail(){
    $response["result"] = "failure";
    $response["message"] = "Invalid email!";
    return json_encode($response);
}
}
```

DBOperations.php:

```
<?php

class DBOperations{

    private $host = '*****';
    private $user = '*****';
    private $db = '*****';
    private $pass = '*****';
    private $conn;


    public function _construct(){
        $this -> conn = new PDO("mysql:host=".$this->host.";dbname=".$this -> db, $this -> user, $this -> pass, array('charset' => 'utf8'));

        $this -> conn -> query("SET CHARACTER SET utf8");
    }

    public function insertData($firstname, $lastname, $gender, $birthday, $email, $username, $password){

        $hashedPassword = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

        $sql = 'INSERT INTO users SET firstname=:firstname, lastname=:lastname, gender=:gender, birthday=:birthday, email=:email, password=:hashedPassword, username=:username, joining_date = now()';

        $query = $this ->conn->prepare($sql);
        $query -> execute(array(':firstname' => $firstname, ':lastname' => $lastname, ':gender' => $gender, ':birthday' => $birthday, ':email' => $email, ':username' => $username, ':hashedPassword' => $hashedPassword));

        if($query){
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }

    public function checkLogin($email, $password){
        $sql = 'SELECT * FROM users WHERE email= :email';
        $query = $this -> conn -> prepare($sql);
        $query -> execute(array(':email' => $email));
        $data = $query -> fetchObject();
        $db_password = $data -> password;


        if ($hashedPasswordCheck = password_verify($password, $db_password)) {
            $user["username"] = $data -> username;
            $user["email"] = $data -> email;
            return $user;

        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public function changePassword($email, $password){

        $hashedPassword = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

        $sql = 'UPDATE users SET password = :hashedPassword WHERE email = :email';
        $query = $this -> conn -> prepare($sql);
        $query -> execute(array(':email' => $email, ':hashedPassword' => $hashedPassword));

        if ($query) {

            return true;

        } else {

            return false;

        }
    }


    public function checkUserExist($email){

        $sql = 'SELECT COUNT(*) from users WHERE email =:email';
        $query = $this -> conn -> prepare($sql);
        $query -> execute(array('email' => $email));

        if($query){

            $row_count = $query -> fetchColumn();

            if ($row_count == 0){

                return false;

            } else {

                return true;

            }
        } else {

            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Now the android files:

```
package de.novee.apps.raivel.register;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;

import de.novee.apps.raivel.LandingActivity;
import de.novee.apps.raivel.R;
import de.novee.apps.raivel.login.LoginActivity;
import de.novee.apps.raivel.loginregistration.Constants;
import de.novee.apps.raivel.loginregistration.RequestInterface;
import de.novee.apps.raivel.models.ServerRequest;
import de.novee.apps.raivel.models.ServerResponse;
import de.novee.apps.raivel.models.User;
import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.Callback;
import retrofit2.Response;
import retrofit2.Retrofit;
import retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonConverterFactory;

public class RegisterSecondActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Intent i;

    View myView;

    String firstname;
    String lastname;
    String birthday;
    String gender;
    String email;
    String username;
    String password;
    String password_repeat;

    private EditText et_email;
    private EditText et_username;
    private EditText et_password;
    private EditText et_password_repeat;
    private ProgressBar progress;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_register_second);

        myView = findViewById(android.R.id.content);

        i = getIntent();
        firstname = i.getExtras().getString("firstname");
        lastname = i.getExtras().getString("lastname");
        birthday = i.getExtras().getString("birthday");
        gender = i.getExtras().getString("gender");


        overridePendingTransition(0, 0);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar_register_second);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Registrierung");
        toolbar.setTitleTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.color_white));

        initViews(myView);

        setupRegisterUser();
        setupGoToLoginButton();
    }

    private void initViews(View view){
        et_email = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_email);
        et_username = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_username);
        et_password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_password);
        et_password_repeat = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_password_repeat);

        progress = (ProgressBar)view.findViewById(R.id.progress);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        if(item.getItemId() == android.R.id.home){
            startActivity(new Intent(RegisterSecondActivity.this, RegisterFirstActivity.class));
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    private void setupRegisterUser(){
        Button btn_registerUser = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_register_final);
        btn_registerUser.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                email = et_email.getText().toString();
                username = et_username.getText().toString();
                password = et_password.getText().toString();
                password_repeat = et_password_repeat.getText().toString();

                if(!firstname.isEmpty() && !lastname.isEmpty() && !birthday.isEmpty() && !gender.isEmpty() && !email.isEmpty() &&
                        !username.isEmpty() && !password.isEmpty() && !password_repeat.isEmpty()){

                    if(password.equals(password_repeat)){
                        progress.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        registerProcess(firstname,lastname,birthday,gender,email,username,password);
                    }else{
                        Snackbar.make(myView, "Passwörter müssen gleich sein!", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }

                }else{
                    Snackbar.make(view, "Felder dürfen nicht leer sein!", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private void setupGoToLoginButton(){
        Button gotoLoginButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_gotologin);
        gotoLoginButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                startActivity(new Intent(RegisterSecondActivity.this, LoginActivity.class));
            }
        });
    }

    private void registerProcess(String firstname, String lastname, String birthday, String gender, String email, String username, String password){
        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(Constants.BASE_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();

        RequestInterface requestInterface = retrofit.create(RequestInterface.class);

        User user = new User();
        user.setFirstname(firstname);
        user.setLastname(lastname);
        user.setBirthday(birthday);
        user.setGender(gender);
        user.setEmail(email);
        user.setUsername(username);
        user.setPassword(password);

        ServerRequest request = new ServerRequest();
        request.setOperation(Constants.REGISTER_OPERATION);
        request.setUser(user);

        Call<ServerResponse> response = requestInterface.operation(request);

        response.enqueue(new Callback<ServerResponse>(){
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<ServerResponse> call, retrofit2.Response<ServerResponse> response) {
                ServerResponse resp = response.body();
                Snackbar.make(myView, resp.getMessage(), Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                progress.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<ServerResponse> call, Throwable t) {
                progress.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                Log.d(Constants.TAG,t.getLocalizedMessage());
                Snackbar.make(myView, t.getLocalizedMessage(), Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });

    }

}
```

ServerRequest.java:

```
package de.novee.apps.raivel.models;


public class ServerRequest {

    private String operation;
    private User user;

    public void setOperation(String operation) {
        this.operation = operation;
    }

    public void setUser(User user) {
        this.user = user;
    }

}
```

ServerResponse.java

```
package de.novee.apps.raivel.models;

public class ServerResponse {

    private String result;
    private String message;
    private User user;

    public String getResult() {
        return result;
    }

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public User getUser() {
        return user;
    }

}
```

RequestInterface:

```
package de.novee.apps.raivel.loginregistration;


import de.novee.apps.raivel.models.ServerRequest;
import de.novee.apps.raivel.models.ServerResponse;

import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.http.Body;
import retrofit2.http.POST;

public interface RequestInterface {
    @POST("apps/raivel/android_api/")
    Call<ServerResponse> operation(@Body ServerRequest request);
}
```

User.java:

```
package de.novee.apps.raivel.models;

public class User {

    private String firstname;
    private String lastname;
    private String gender;
    private String birthday;
    private String email;
    private String username;
    private String password;
    private String oldPassword;
    private String newPassword;

    public String getFirstname() {
        return firstname;
    }

    public void setFirstname(String firstname) {
        this.firstname = firstname;
    }

    public String getLastname() {
        return lastname;
    }

    public void setLastname(String lastname) {
        this.lastname = lastname;
    }

    public String getGender() {
        return gender;
    }

    public void setGender(String gender) {
        this.gender = gender;
    }

    public String getBirthday() {
        return birthday;
    }

    public void setBirthday(String birthday) {
        this.birthday = birthday;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getOldPassword() {
        return oldPassword;
    }

    public void setOldPassword(String oldPassword) {
        this.oldPassword = oldPassword;
    }

    public String getNewPassword() {
        return newPassword;
    }

    public void setNewPassword(String newPassword) {
        this.newPassword = newPassword;
    }
}
```

I get 'failed' in the Logs and on click on Register in the app I get snackbar message 'End of input at line 1 column 1'.

My php files are saved on my site at 'www.novee.de/apps/raivel/android_api/..'

There is one more Constants.java file but I think it is not important to post it. I know it is much code but I am looking for a solution since days maybe weeks and could find nothing. So I hope you guys can take some time and help me to understand this error.

If I made something wrong with this post, please tell me.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the salt on the password hash on creation.

There is need to play with salts when using `password_hash`, that is handled internally to `password_hash`.

The salt is random and catenated with the password on creation (`password_hash`) but it is not catenated with the password on verification (`password_verify`) so there can be no match.

PHP 5.5 provides [a native password hashing API](http://php.net/manual/en/book.password.php) that safely handles both [hashing](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) and [verifying passwords](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) in a secure manner.

Comment: But should I not get another error msg instead of 'End of Input at line 1 column 1' , if the problem is in the hash section?

Comment: First you need to fix the hash then there maybe other issues. There is no point in "if-what" while there is a known error.

Comment: okay I changed everything and still get 'End of Input at line 1 column 1'.. edited code above also.

Comment: You need to debug! Go caveman debugging, add print statements and find where the error occurs. Learning to debug is more important that learning a language. It is like learning to ride a bicycle, the only way is by doing.:

Comment: First of all: thank you for the kick in the ass. After debugging i found a typo in the php script. Now i got a new error message. But i will try to solve it on myself.